# PDO insert issue

Tags: php, pdo

I've created a new function with PDO to insert data in my database.

The function looks like this

```
    function insert($table,$column = array(),$value = array())
{
    $array1 = implode(",", $column);
    $array2 = implode(",", $value);

    try 
    { 
        $sql = $this->connect->query("INSERT INTO $table ($array1) VALUES ($array2)");  


    }  
    catch(PDOException $e) 
    {  
        echo $e->getMessage();  
    }  
}
```

and the call for the function like this

```
-> insert('coupons',array('categorie','name','link','code','id'),array('test11','test','test','test','NULL'));
```

but after all, it seems not to work and isn't showing any error. Do someone have a few points for me, where I should search the mistake? When I write the query /wo the varibales and call the function, it works. Even with the first two variables it works. Only the last one ($array2) seems to have a "bug".

Comment: I recommend against such a design. For starters, it doesn't utilize the main benefits of PDO, namely binding parameters and protecting against SQL Injection.

Comment: what do you mean by binding the paramerters? Like splitting the query and reassamble it on the end ?

Comment: [`bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I will use it in my code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're inserting strings, which means your query comes out

```
INSERT INTO coupons (categorie, name, ...) VALUES (test11, test, ...)
```

bare strings are interpreted as field/table names, meaning your query is completely invalid.

At bare minimum, ignoring all the other problems with this code, the fix would be

```
$array2 = implode("','", $value);
                   ^-^---

INSERT INTO $table ($array) VALUES ('$array2');
                                    ^--     ^--
```

of course, this is ignoring the sql injection vulnerabilities, keyword problems, blah blah blah.